# Is there a device with multi auxiliary (AUX) ports to configure multiple devices

Tags: networking, port, switch, serial

Level: Beginner

Sorry for the confusing title. I shall try to explain my best to explain my question.

**Question**: Is there a networking device named `X` that has multiple AUX ports so that I can connect other networking devices that can be configured from AUX port to this `device-X` and then configure these devices by connecting my PC to the `device-X`. The image below describes the question more better.

Is there a networking `device-X` that is capable of doing what a `Device-???` in red color is shown in the image below is doing:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What kind of AUX port? RS-232?

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't know that exactly. But it is almost the same type as AUX on switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the AUX ports you're talking about are serial ports, then you're looking for a terminal server - the old kind, not the Windows/GUI kind. Also called a console server.

Here's a whole bunch of them.

http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Results.aspx/Networking/Terminal-Servers/n-4294958513